# Laravel db issue with group by and strict false

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, group-by

having the following laravel db query and on database config 'strict'=> false

```
DB::table('supply as s')
            ->select(
                DB::raw('WEEKOFYEAR(zeit_von) as week'), DB::raw('round(count(s.id)/8,2) as slots_count'),
                's.projekt', 'pas.skillset'
            )
            ->leftJoin('p_projects as p', 'p.id', '=', 's.projekt')
            ->leftJoin('accounts_skillset as pas', 'pas.account_id', '=', 's.employee')
            ->where('s.deleted', 0)
            ->whereIn('s.supply_status', [1, 2])
            ->whereRaw(
                DB::raw("(select count(cal_id) from w_cal as c
                    where c.owner=s.employee
                    and deleted=0
                    and date_format(s.time_from, '%d.%m.%y')=date_format(from_unixtime(c.mdatetime), '%d.%m.%y')
                    and c.category='Kr')<1")
            )
            ->whereRaw(DB::raw('year(time_from)='.$year))
            ->groupBy('pas.skillset', 'p.id', DB::raw('WEEKOFYEAR(s.time_from)'))
            ->get();
```

I get `s.projekt' isn't in GROUP BY`

mysql server version 5.5.5

if I copy paste the query and run in console is working fine

on newer mariadb is working fine

Comment: Verify [`@@SESSION.sql_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting) variable, specifically if it includes [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) value in Laravel sessión.

Comment: if I run `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` there is no result

Comment: i've same issue do you found any solution?